# How do I align text after the table with column where the table is started?

Tags: captions, align

After the caption of the a table, I have few lines of text which I like to be aligned from where the table is started.

The table is centered aligned, how can I find the column from which the table is started so to say the text lines be placed there?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\setlength{\columnsep}{25 pt} % Distance between two columns
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} % page layout
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multicol,tabularx,capt-of}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Pin no} & \textbf{Pin name} & \textbf{Pin type} & \textbf{Function} \\
\hline
A1 & TST1 & AO & Test pin \\
\hline
A2 & VDDF & P & Analog reference voltage, internally generated \\
\hline
A3 & \# INT & DO & Interrupt, active low\\
\hline
A4 & CLK & DI & FPGA clock \\
\hline
A5 & SDO & DO & Serial data out\\
\hline
B1 & VDDA & P & Analog supply voltage\\
\hline
B2 & TST2 & AO & Test pin \\
\hline
B3 & AGND & P & Analog ground \\
\hline
B4 & \# RESET & DI & FPGA reset, active low \\
\hline
B5 & VDD1 & P & Digital core voltage, internally generated \\
\hline
Y1 & VREF & P & Analog reference voltage, internally generated\\
\hline
Y2 & AGND & P & Analog ground \\
\hline
Y3 & DGND & P & Digital ground \\
\hline
Y4 & \# CS & DI & SPI chip select, active low \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Pin name and description}
\end{center}

AI Analog input \\
AO Analog output \\
DI Digital input \\
DO Digital output \\
P Power \\
Note: Pin names beginning with a \# character denotes that the single is active low.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend the package `threeparttable` for this? I think this should be exactly what you are trying to achieve. Like this, the table notes will stick to the table and are semantically nice coded. If you put the caption to the top (as I always do for tables), it will look even better.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[] place some limitations here, if you want to stop the floating.
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
\textbf{Pin no} & \textbf{Pin name} & \textbf{Pin type} & \textbf{Function} \\
\midrule
A1 & TST1 & AO & Test pin \\
A2 & VDDF & P & Analog reference voltage, internally generated \\
A3 & \# INT & DO & Interrupt, active low\\
A4 & CLK & DI & FPGA clock \\
A5 & SDO & DO & Serial data out\\
B1 & VDDA & P & Analog supply voltage\\
B2 & TST2 & AO & Test pin \\
B3 & AGND & P & Analog ground \\
B4 & \# RESET & DI & FPGA reset, active low \\
B5 & VDD1 & P & Digital core voltage, internally generated \\
Y1 & VREF & P & Analog reference voltage, internally generated\\
Y2 & AGND & P & Analog ground \\
Y3 & DGND & P & Digital ground \\
Y4 & \# CS & DI & SPI chip select, active low \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Pin name and description} % set this in front of \toprule in order to get the notes closer to the table
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft] % you may leave the default (no options) if you like. Like this it is left aligned as you asked for.
\item AI Analog input
\item AO Analog output
\item DI Digital input
\item DO Digital output
\item P Power
\item Note: Pin names beginning with a \# character denotes that the single is active low.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may use this solution for your table as well. I just changed to the use of `booktabs` as I think it is easier to read and has nicer vertical spacing. You can easily wrap your original MWE in such a `threeparttable`.